# Does Jupyter support 'read-only' notebooks?

Tags: python, django, pandas, web, jupyter

My team is currently developing a fairly quick clustering job using Pandas for business analysts. We're planning on hosting a local server where the end user can input a few parameters to be used during the routine execution, which will access an internal database and then return a CSV file.

A Jupyter server would be ideal for us, but the problem is that we can't have the user being able to edit the underlying code - all he needs to do is supply the parameters and start job execution. Converting it to HMTL, I think, turns everything static and means we can't delived updated data on demand.

Plan B is just making a small django app but I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish what I need with Jupyter itself, or else if there's any better alternative for similar use cases? We don't even plan to display any widgets, just provide the user with the raw data output.

thanks in advance

Comment: flask is more lightweight than django and may better serve your needs ... but there are about a million ways to skin this cat (a jupyter notebook is probably one of the worst)

Comment: you can access your django models/views inside a notebook ;D

Answer (score 10):

The notebook file can have its write permissions unset:

```
$ chmod -w notebook.ipynb
```

The notebook is still interactive, but the notebook file will not change.

[image: Save symbol disabled with title "This notebook is read-only"]

Answer (score 6):

There is also an notebook extension, [Freeze](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/freeze) which allows to lock (allow execution but not edit cell contents) or freeze (disables editing and execution) individual code cells or markdown blocks. This is important as order of execution for code cells matters while running notebook. [This presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1n2RlMdmv1p25Xy5thJUhkKGvjtV-dkAIsUXP-AL4ffI/edit#slide=id.g3cb1319227_1_405) at JupyterCon has more details on it.

Answer (score -1):

just try eval this line in your browser console:

```
Jupyter.notebook.writable = false;
```

this will make current jupyter notebook file not writable, so any changes would not be allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by "browser console"?

Comment: Right click in the browser and click "Inspect" if you are using Google Chrome

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding OP's question, but calling that JS line in your browser console will only apply the changes to you, on the given page. It has no impact to anybody else and the change won't persist after a page refresh.

Comment: @MeltedPenguin Yes you are right, the JS line works only in the current window in the browser.